# Handling try except multiple times while web scraping BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

while web scraping using BeautifulSoup I have to write try except multiple times. See the code below:

```
try:
    addr1 = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'addr1'}).text
except:
    addr1 = ''

try:
    addr2 = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'addr2'}).text
except:
    addr2 = ''

try:
    city = soup.find('strong', {'class' : 'city'}).text
except:
    city = ''
```

The problem is that I have to write try except multiple times and that is very annoying. I want to write a function to handle the exception.

I tried to use the following function but it is still showing an error:

```
def datascraping(var):

    try:
        return var
    except:
        return None

addr1 = datascraping(soup.find('span', {'class' : 'addr1'}).text)
addr2 = datascraping(soup.find('span', {'class' : 'addr2'}).text)
```

Can anyone help me to solve the issue?

Comment: "is still showing an error:" - what error?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Also: `var`is a value. It'll be computed when the `datascraping` function is called, so it will throw the error outside your try handling code. If you want to do it this way, you need a higher order function - `datascraping` should take a lambda that will return the value. Then the lambda can be run inside your `try` block.

Comment: Try: `addr1 = getattr(soup.find('span', {'class': 'addr1'}), 'text', '')`. This fixes the exception on accessing the `text` attribute from `None`. If `soup.find` raises other exceptions you'll have to handle in some other way

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop that iterates through a sequence containing your arguments.  Then use a conditional statement that checks if the return value is `None`, prior to attempting to get the `text` attribute.  Then store the results in a dictionary.  This way there is no need to use `try`/`except` at all.

```
seq = [('span', 'addr1'), ('span', 'addr2'), ('strong', 'city')]
results = {}
for tag, value in seq:
    var = soup.find(tag, {'class': value})
    if var is not None:
        results[value] = var.text
    else:
        results[value] = ''
```